Please help find my error in comparing two acceleration equations
Please help me figure out where my mistake is when comparing two acceleration formulas and coming up with $4x^2 = x^2$. Thank you in advance.
The Kinematic Equations say:

$v^2 = v_0^2 + 2aΔx$


$Δx = v_0t + ½at^2$

When starting velocity $v_0 = 0$ and starting position $x_0 = 0$

$v^2 = 2ax$


$x = ½at^2$

Rearranging

$a = \frac{v^2} {2x}$


$a = \frac{2x} {t^2}$

Both are equivalent for acceleration so:

$\frac{v^2} {2x} = \frac{2x} {t^2}$

Cross Multiply

$4x^2 = v^2 t^2$

We know velocity is $\frac{displacement}{time}$ with beginning position = 0

$v = \frac{x}{t}$ and $v^2 = \frac{x^2}{t^2}$

Substitute for $v^2$ in $4x^2 = v^2 t^2$

$4x^2 = (\frac{x^2}{t^2}) {t^2}$

And finally we get:

$4x^2 = x^2$


One of your $v$ variables is the final velocity and one is the average velocity.   Under constant (non-zero) acceleration, these two velocities cannot be equal and your substitution of one for the other is invalid.

After looking at it over and over... I finally get that v = Δx/t is always average velocity even when setting beginning x to zero. x is final and I mistakenly applied the "final" label to the velocity as well. Thank you.

$$ v = \frac{x}{t} $$
is only valid for constant velocity. You already have the correct equation for $x$ with constant acceleration, namely
$$ x = \frac{1}{2}a t^2 $$

Doesn't the formula calculate Average Velocity whether or not velocity is constant? I understand now (based on the other answer) that it was invalid to use Average Velocity for my substitution when it was supposed to be final velocity.

Yes, and we normally use a different symbol, like $\overline v$ for that. This way we avoid confusion like the one displayed in your question :)
